# How to optimize LINQ to Entities retrieving top x records from a navigation property

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, ef-core-6.0

Let's suppose we have to retrieve from the DB one record from BlogPost (Id = 123) and its most 5 recent comments, we would probably write something like:

```
var test = _db.BlogPost.Select(x => new blogDTO()
{
    Id = x.Id,
    PostText = x.PostText,
    Comments = x.Comments.OrderByDescending(o => o.Ts).Take(5).Select(c => new commentDTO() { Text = c.CommentText }).ToList()
}).Where(x => x.Id == 123).ToList();
```

This would be translated in a very inefficient SQL:

```
SELECT [i].[Id], [i].[PostText], [t0].[CommentText], [t0].[Id]
FROM [BlogPost] AS [i]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[CommentText], [t].[Id], [t].[BlogPostId], [t].[Ts]
    FROM (
        SELECT [i0].[CommentText] AS [CommentText], [i0].[Id], [i0].[BlogPostId], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [i0].[BlogPostId] ORDER BY [i0].[Ts] DESC) AS [row], [i0].[Ts]
        FROM [Comments] AS [i0]
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 5
) AS [t0] ON [i].[Id] = [t0].[BlogPostId]
WHERE [i].[Id] = 813
ORDER BY [i].[Id], [t0].[BlogPostId], [t0].[Ts] DESC
```

While probably the SQL should read something like:

```
SELECT Id, CommentText, Ts from (
SELECT [i].[Id], ic.CommentText, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [ic].[BlogPostId] ORDER BY [ic].[Ts] DESC) AS [row], [ic].[Ts]
FROM [BlogPost] AS [i]
left join Comments as ic on ic.BlogPostId = i.Id
WHERE [i].[Id] = 813 ) as res
where res.row <= 5
```

Do you know how the LINQ to Entities code could be better written?
Or do you feel this is something the EF team should look into?

Comment: Any proof that the EF generated is *"very inefficient SQL"*? Both SQLs look the same to me (it shouldn't matter for nowadays database query optimizers if you use nested subqueries or not). The only difference I see is that the EF generated has additional order by, which however is needed for collection  materialization.

Comment: Yes, on a db with about 2 millions comments, the first runs in 5 seconds while the second in a few ms.

Comment: Try `AsSplitQuery()`, probably it should be faster.

Comment: It isn't @SvyatoslavDanyliv, it does two queries: the first is very simple and fast (it simply gets the BlogPost), the second is basically the same it does without AsSplitQuery()

Comment: It is more a workaround than a solution but adding

Comments = x.Comments. **Where(x => x.BlogPostId == 123)** .OrderByDescending[...]

works better